# Show active speaker in the another div (agora web SDK)

Tags: agora.io, videocall

I am using agora web SDK, and I want to show the active speaker in the center of the screen(like the google meet sidebar feature). How can I do that?

I tried to replace the HTML using jQuery to center the div, but it's not rendering the video.